# Android: Align a Button to the Right in LinearLayout

Tags: android, button

I have a piece of code which I use to create a new `LinearLayout`. Within the layout I wish to add a `TextView` which contains both a label and a value. Then next to it on the right I want to display the button. I want the button to be located toward the end of the screen, without stretching the button. I am happy with the button width and height as `WARP_CONTENT`.

How can I achieve this in code? I have barely any `XML` so using `XML` is not an option. I am trying to make the app as dynamic as possible, so I decided to steer clear of `XML`.

Please see the code below:

```
    // Build a button
    final Button addButton = new Button(task.getParent());
    addButton.setText("Add New");
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // Open a file picker here to let the user pick a file
        }
    });

    // Build a new layout to hold all the elements
    LinearLayout verticalLayout = new LinearLayout(task.getParent());
    verticalLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    verticalLayout.addView(sizeTextView);
    verticalLayout.addView(addButton);
```

Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: * set layout gravity for verticalLayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: Add Space (View) between TextView & Button.

```
    // View space = new View(parent_context);
    View space = new View(task.getParent());

    // Width:0dp, Height:1 & Weight: 1.0
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams spaceLP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 1, 1.0f);
    space.setLayoutParams(spaceLP);

    verticalLayout.addView(sizeTextView);

    verticalLayout.addView(space);

    verticalLayout.addView(addButton);
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this works for me as I am using API level 15 and the solutions mentioned above require API level 17 and I am trying not to use the support libs

Answer (score 0):

Add textview with size and gravity,like this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.setLayoutDirection(Gravity.RIGHT|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);      
verticalLayout.addView(sizeTextView,params);
```

Comment: I am using API level 15  and these use API level 17. I am trying to steer clear of the support libs at this time. Is there a different way in which I can achieve similar results using API 15?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you should use Relative layout and RelativeLayout.LayoutParams. By using LayoutParams you can set the rule to align your views as per your requirements.

for example

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =  (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)button.getLayoutParams();
 params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
 params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.id_to_be_left_of);
  button.setLayoutParams(params);
```